# jQuery Smooth Scroll From an external link

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am going out of my freaking mind trying to figure this out, relativly a noob so I forgive me if this is super simple.

I have a fixed header and I have figured out how to subtract the height of the header in the function. When I click the links when I am on the same page, the smooth scroll works perfect. When I click the same link from an external page it loads but does not recognize the header off set.

Ex.

```
<a href="mypage#link1"> clicked on http://mypage/ = correct results

<a href="mypage#link1"> clicked on http://mypage/other_page = incorrect results

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   $(function() {

   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {

   if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

   var target = $(this.hash);

   target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

       if (target.length) {

         $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top - 81
           }, 800);
       return false;
       }
     }

    });

  });

});
```

I am sure that I am missing something, I think that the if statement should include a condition to check and then deal with the fact that it is coming from another page. As easy as this should be, it is kicking my but!!! So any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell you're only catching the click event on links on that page... that won't work when a link on a different page is clicked, as no click event is fired on the target page (and the originating page has absolutely no control over the destination)...

So you need to catch the hash on page load (ie. directly inside your `jQuery(document).ready()` function) and do a scroll animation inside that.

Additionally you probably need to prevent the browser from "automagically" scrolling to the destination scroll-point before you even have a chance to animate - which is probably what you are seeing right now, as that has been the default behavior of AFAIK all browsers since the dawn of named anchors.

You could go about that two ways:

1. Use something other than named anchors, which browsers won't recognize natively... This will mean that browsers that do not support whatever you end out with wont degradde gracefully (ie. they won't scroll to the correct point at all)
2. Reset the scroll position to (0,0) on page load and then do your animation afterwards. It may be necessary to wrap this in a setTimeout with a 1 ms delay or somthing to get it working across browsers.

This works in firefox, probably other browsers as well:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(function() {
        var target = $('[name=' + location.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').css({
                scrollTop: 0
            }).animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top - 81
            }, 800);
        }
        $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 81
                    }, 800);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed example and response. I am still not able to get it to work with the fixed menu. and switching from page to page, not even in Firefox. I don't know if this makes a difference but it is a WordPress website. I don't think I mentioned that above, sorry I was losing my mind a bit.

I did add the delay to the animation and even wrapped it with a setTimeout() function but nada. Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me... You are using named anchors like `<a name="link1" />` for your target positions, right? -Try posting some more of your code or a link to a live demonstration... It shouldn't matter that it's wordpress, as long as your code is actually in the resulting source code (ie. you may have put it in a hook that is never called or something like that...)

Comment: I am using href links like href="mypage#location"